# How to read csv with WKT geometry in Arcmap?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, gdal, ogr, csv, well-known-text

I have found several parcels I need on a county map viewer. However, the only option to download any of the data is found on a click context menu to "Copy selection as csv" which gives me this:

```
HGID,ShapeWKT,parcelnumber,locationstreet,owner2,totalassd,parcelid,sec,ownerzip1,ownermailing1,rge,ownerstate,owner1,ownercity,formattedparcel,twp
"13514","POLYGON((825759.0653999997 326186.8526000008,825590.3153999997 326176.4357999992,825572.2887000003 326356.2666999996,825741.2658000002 326367.40330000035,825759.0653999997 326186.8526000008))","1406130003000009000","1470  HIGHWAY M","","9810","10682","13","63902","P O BOX 1021"," 5","MO","RHODES FREDERICK & PATRICIA","POPLAR BLUFF","14-06-13.0-003-000-009.000","24"
"13512","POLYGON((825759.0653999997 326186.8526000008,825770.4408999998 326065.06709999964,825776.7737999997 325997.26920000085,825727.1403000002 325988.53079999983,825720.1957999999 325559.36419999966,825716.0288000003 325041.31090000086,825380.9403999997 325018.1026000008,825384.6557 325291.9681000002,825387.7232999997 325518.09530000016,825390.7329000003 325739.9436000008,825393.6021999997 325951.46199999936,825395.5236999998 326093.1026000008,825399.5045999996 326344.8791000005,825572.2887000003 326356.2666999996,825590.3153999997 326176.4357999992,825759.0653999997 326186.8526000008))","1406130003000010000","M HWY","","10530","10683","13","63901","1563 M HWY"," 5","MO","MORGAN SHERMAN F & MARY I","POPLAR BLUFF","14-06-13.0-003-000-010.000","24"
```

I pasted this into a text editor, but I am unfamilliar with the file format. It is not a point based csv that could be added to ArcMap using Display XY data. It looks like it may be some type of OGR file like this (http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html).

Is there a way to convert the csv file to a format readable in ArcMap rather than using GDAL?

It looks like I may be able to creat an associated .vrt file, but I am not sure where I could go from here as far as getting the data into ArcMap. VRT might look something like this something like this:

```
 <OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="test">
        <SrcDataSource>parcels.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the geometry is in the WTK-format and is of the type polygon, you will specify this in your vrt-file. So your vrt file should look someting like this:

```
 <OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="parcel">
        <SrcDataSource>parcel.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPolygon</GeometryType>
        <GeometryField encoding="WKT" field="ShapeWKT"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

With ogr2ogr you can convert this to a shapefile or a filegeodatabse to open the file in ArcGIS:

```
ogr2ogr -f FileGDB test.gdb  test.vrt
```

Comment: ogr2ogr will expect the OGRVRTLayer value to match the csv's file name, in this case you'd replace "test" with "parcel". You may also want to add an entry for the LayerSRS value to set the coordinate system.  If not, it's no big deal since you can use Toolbox to fix it later.

Answer (score 2):

You could also write a python scrip to read the data, and output a feature class.  There is an arcpy python [FromWKT](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000008s000000) function.